# Place a % of text on line 1 and the rest on line 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a value displayed into a paragraph element (from ACF on WordPress).

The paragraph is into a div with a max-width, and text-centered.

I'm looking to find a way to say :

"If the default display of the text is on one line : 70% of the text will be displayed on a first line, the rest on the second line".

Example : 
https://prnt.sc/njoc6x
With the solution (which I don't have) : 
https://prnt.sc/njob94

Like this, I will avoid a block with just one or two words on a second line.

Please tell me if it's not enough clear :)

Comment: Can you add the corresponding HTML and CSS? And also what you tried?

Comment: Use js. Step 1) test the length of your text to see if it's within your boundary. 2) If it's within the boundary then use css to prevent word-wrap, if it's outside then use see to force word-wrap

Comment: Do you have the actual HTML code for us? This way we can give you a more accurate solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could go with `width:70%` on the paragraph but I've set margins so that there's 15% left and right (30%) leaving a 70% area for text. If you want the text to be extendable though, I'd suggest using a textarea ?

```css
#textcenter{
background-color:grey;
height:200px;
}


#textcenter p{
padding-top: 45px;
font-size:16pt;
text-align:center;
color:white;
margin:0 15%; /*15% left and right - 30% margin = 70% text area*/
}

#textcenter textarea{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
color:grey;
width:70%;
margin:0 15%;
}
```

```html
<div id="textcenter">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ut.</p> 
<br>
<textarea>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ut.<!--editable--></textarea> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, amazing ! Thank you Rachel ! :)

Comment: No bother... Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

instead of `max-width:70%;` you should use `width: 70%`  and `margin: 0 auto;` for center your text